# Retrieve all records in a table with nHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I need to retrieve all the records in a table with nHibernate.  If I had the key for all the records in the table I could loop and use nHibernate's `Get` method (this seems inefficient though) but I don't have the keys.  I could also use `FindAll` but this requires criteria or a stored procedure.

How can I get all the records from the table?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

SQL tables are mapped to classes so in order to retrieve all records from a table you write a query (HQL or Criteria) that fetches all the objects for a given typed mapped to this table:

```
var products = session.CreateCriteria<Product>().List<Product>();
```

or using HQL:

```
var products = session.CreateQuery("from " + typeof(Product)).List<Product>();
```

or LINQ:

```
var products = session.Linq<Product>().ToList() // 2.x contrib provider
var products = session.Query<Product>().ToList() // 3.x integrated provider
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you basically create criteria with no restrictions?

Comment: exactly, isn't that the requirement?

Comment: Yes. I just wanted to make sure I knew what was going on. Thanks!